# I need the right query for the following

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the "Customers" table

```
ID  Name Country
1   A   UK
2   B   CN
3   C   IN
4   D   GB
5   E   CN
6   F   GB
7   H   UK
8   I   IN
```

Need a query to show number of customers for each country. GB and UK should be considered as single country.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  You should show what you have tried, and if doesn't work, then someone can help refine it.

Comment: i tried this but doesn't get the full answer.. 
remember gb and uk should be considered as single country..
SELECT COUNT(Id), Country 
  FROM Customer
 GROUP BY Country

Comment: Can you provide a column to determine which countries belong together?

Comment: Hi @IqraAslam!  To avoid being downvoted in the future, it may help to review our [ask] page.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN country = 'GB' THEN 'UK' ELSE country END) as country,
       COUNT(*), Country
FROM Customer
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN country = 'GB' THEN 'UK' ELSE country END);
```